# How to convert 60-ticks-per-seconds to floating-point seconds?

Tags: time, timer

*I know there is a number of* similar *questions on Stackoverflow, but this one has a few unique requirements.*

I have a ticking mechanism which generates 60 ticks per 1 second(so, 120 ticks would be 2 seconds), which I didn't design (or have any control over), but I need to work with it.

I need to somehow convert these ticks into decimal seconds. Another problems is that the language I am working with only supports integers (it is a deprecated language for an old scripting platform). Friend asked me to convert those ticks to seconds in a floating-point decimal format.

So, What I have right now (only the logic, the language is weird and there is no tag for it on SO):

```
full_seconds     = ticks / 60;
second_fragment  = time % 60;


//If you're wondering wth this is it is because time % 60 sometimes returns 1-9, and they are not preceded by a zero, and I simply concatenate it below.

second fragment = (second_fragment < 10) ? "0"+second_fragment : second_fragment);

write(full_seconds+"."+second_fragment)
```

Now, you can probably guess the problem: The script *counts up* to `0.59` and then it sets to `1.0` and so on.

Comment: fractional seconds = second_fragment * 100 / 60.0

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Oh, that solved it! Thanks! :D (You should post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, as mentioned by [@AkiSuihkonen in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277308/how-to-convert-60-ticks-per-seconds-to-floating-point-seconds#comment18099585_13277308):

```
second_fragment = time % 60 * 100 / 60;
```